# How to append content inside several divs - before the closing tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

At web pages representing [player profiles](http://preferans.de/DE28815) I currently have this JavaScipt code:

```
    var CHARTS = ['money', 'matches', 'game', 'pass', 'misere', 'catch'];
    var mobile = (/Android|iPhone|iPad|iPod|Blackberry|BB10/i.test(navigator.userAgent));

    if (!mobile) {
            $.each(CHARTS, function(index, title) {
                    $('#' + title + '_table').hide();
                    $('#' + title + '_button').button().click(function() {
                            $('#' + title + '_table').toggle();
                    });
            });
    }
```

And this HTML-code (please look at the last 2 lines in each XXX_tab `div`):

```
<div id="money_tab">
        <div id="money_chart" class="gchart"></div>
        <div id="money_slider" class="jslider"></div>
        <p><input type="button" value="Table" id="money_button"></p>
        <div id="money_table" class="gtable"></div>
</div>

<div id="matches_tab">
        <div id="matches_chart" class="gchart"></div>
        <div id="matches_slider" class="jslider"></div>
        <p><input type="button" value="Table" id="matches_button"></p>
        <div id="matches_table" class="gtable"></div>
</div>

<div id="game_tab">
        <div id="game_chart" class="gchart"></div>
        <p><input type="button" value="Table" id="game_button"></p>
        <div id="game_table" class="gtable"></div>
</div>

<div id="pass_tab">
        <div id="pass_chart" class="gchart"></div>
        <p><input type="button" value="Table" id="pass_button"></p>
        <div id="pass_table" class="gtable"></div>
</div>

<div id="misere_tab">
        <div id="misere_chart" class="gchart"></div>
        <p><input type="button" value="Table" id="misere_button"></p>
        <div id="misere_table" class="gtable"></div>
</div>

<div id="catch_tab">
        <div id="catch_chart" class="gchart"></div>
        <p><input type="button" value="Table" id="catch_button"></p>
        <div id="catch_table" class="gtable"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to reduce the repetitious HTML-code by JavaScript, which would [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) these 2 lines before the end of each `div` tag:

```
        <p><input type="button" value="Table" id="catch_button"></p>
        <div id="catch_table" class="gtable"></div>
```

But I wonder, how to do it with jQuery? I can not just:

```
$.each(CHARTS, function(index, title) {
        $('#' + title + '_chart').append('XXX the 2 lines XXX');
        $('#' + title + '_table').hide();
        $('#' + title + '_button').button().click(function() {
                $('#' + title + '_table').toggle();
        });
});
```

because sometimes there is a slider after the chart.

**So my question is:** using jQuery, how to add stuff before each `<\div>` tag?

Comment: Seems like more of a logic problem rather than a programming question. Under what circumstances is there a slider after the chart?

Comment: No, my question is: how to add stuff before each `<\div>`?

Comment: will you be able add a class attribute to all the div's ... like `<div id="money_tab" class="chart">` and `<div id="misere_tab" class="chart">`

Comment: Yes I can add that class, but my problem is: inside of a tab div I sometimes have just a chart. And sometimes a chart and a slider. I want to add stuff after each chart OR after each chart+slider. But NOT between a chart and a slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class `chart` to the tab elements

```
var CHARTS = ['money', 'matches', 'game', 'pass', 'misere', 'catch'];
var mobile = (/Android|iPhone|iPad|iPod|Blackberry|BB10/i.test(navigator.userAgent));

if (!mobile) {
    var $charts = $('.chart').append('<p><input type="button" value="Table" class="gbutton"></p><div class="gtable"></div>');
    $charts.find('.gtable').hide();
    $charts.find('.gbutton').button().click(function(){
        $(this).parent().next().toggle()
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$.each(CHARTS, function(index, title) {
    if(! $('#'+title+'_tab').find('#'+title+'_button'').length)// check the element is exists or not
    {
       // use tab in place of chart
       $('#' + title + '_tab').append('XXX the 2 lines XXX');
    }

    $('#' + title + '_table').hide();
    $('#' + title + '_button').button().click(function() {
        $('#' + title + '_table').toggle();
    });
});
```